# Auto incrementing w/ a vb.net chart control

Tags: vb.net, graphics, charts

I'm curious to know if the DataVisualization.charting.chart in vb.net does any auto counting / plotting for my particular issue.

I have a file with thousands of User Agent Strings which were generated over a period of time. The UA Strings are generated from user logins.

In my program, I am identifying approximately 45 different environments as: Operating Systems + Browser Type (ie., "Windows 7 + IE10"). Each login also has a date stamp in the format of YYYY-MM.

My task is to do a line chart where I have Environment (Y-axis) vs Date (X-axis) using the vb.net charting control. I would like the control to increment each time I have a particular data set rather than keeping a hideous amount of arrays & counter data for my chart.

Does the vb.net charting control auto increment in this way? I am not able to find anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question (what is it that you want to auto increment? The axis min/max? The date? Something else?), but if you want the axes to update each time you add a new point, the chart certainly supports that. Just call `Chart.ResetAutoValues()` after you add the new point(s), and it will figure out new ranges for both axes.

Edit: Arrange your data before adding it to the chart. Something like:

```
Dictionary<string, int> values = new ...;
string[] uaStrings = ReadFileOfUAStrings();
foreach (string uaString in uaStrings)
{
    values[uaString]++;
}

foreach (KVP in values)
{
    chart.Series(kvp.Key).Points.Add(kvp.Value);
}
```

The above doesn't separate things out by date, but you should get the idea. As written, it's also not very efficient if another UA string is added to the file and the whole thing is re-read, but optimizations can come after it's functional.

Comment: I'll look into the ResetAutoValues method. As I mentioned, I need to plot all my data on an X/Y axis. X = Date; Y = Env. Here is a sample from StatCounter: http://gs.statcounter.com/

Comment: To provide an example, the code below will plot the data only one point at a time. What I would like to do is not keep the counter variable, but rather have the chart control do this. So every time the code is called below, the chart would auto increment by one. The code is only example and doesn't work for what I'm attempting to do.

`Chart1.Series("Win XP + IE10").Points.AddXY("2013-01", 1)`

Comment: Is the data static? Or are there new UA strings coming in? I also didn't realize you were creating a different series for each possible environment... Rather than trying to keep track of counters and such for 45 different environments, arrange your data before adding it to the chart. See my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, I have an xls data file that's static. It's a DB extract from the production environment.

Comment: Then yeah, just read the whole file in and do all the counting before doing anything with the chart, as my edited answer shows.